# PHP sorting arrays numerically by key value

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm trying to sort several arrays in numerical order based on the value in their first key:

```
$array1[0] = '1';
$array1[1] = 'content';
$array1[2] = 'more content';

$array3[0] = '3';
$array3[1] = 'content';
$array3[2] = 'more content';

$array4[0] = '4';
$array4[1] = 'content';
$array4[2] = 'more content';

$array2[0] = '2';
$array2[1] = 'content';
$array2[2] = 'more content';

$arrays = array($array1, $array3, $array4, $array2);

foreach ($arrays as $array) {

echo $array[0] . ' ' . $array[1] . ' ' . $array[2] . '<br>';

}
```

That outputs the arrays in a '1, 3, 4, 2' sequence, I need them to be output thusly: '1, 2, 3, 4'. Not sure how or even if to use the ksort/asort/array_multisort functions here.

Comment: Been a while since I did any PHP coding but this looks like a case for asort, since that will sort it based on values. Put it through asort and then display the array ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a custom comparison function that you then can use with [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) or [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return intval($a[0]) - intval($b[0]);
}
usort($arrays, 'cmp');
```

As of PHP 5.3 you could also use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) for the comparison function:

```
usort($arrays, function($a, $b) { return intval($a[0]) - intval($b[0]); });
```

You could also use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort), create an array of the keys that are to be sorted first and use it to sort the array items itself:

```
$keys = array();
foreach ($arrays as $array) $keys[] = intval($array[0]);
array_multisort($keys, $arrays);
```

Doing this prevents calling the comparing function for each pair of values that is compared as only the key values are compared.

Comment: I think that because the first index of the array is being specified as a string it's possibly safer to use intval() on the value first otherwise it might be doing a string comparison?

Comment: @acqu13sce: Yes, you’re right. String comparison could yield to unexpected results as e.g. `"2" > "12"`.

Comment: LOL, this is more complicated than I thought it would be. I'm liking the array_multisort approach, never used it before tho so could you flesh it out for me a bit more, primarily the output aspect? And is the omission of a { after the foreach statement by design?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I got it working using usort instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using usort you can specify your own sorting criteria on an array. This is an idea of how you could achieve what you ask for

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
  if ($a == $b) {
      return 0;
  }
  return (intval($a[0]) < intval($b[0])) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arrays, "cmp");
```